# X-Bar theory and Trees

Tags: syntax, syntax-trees, x-bar-theory

I am studying linguistics and now this semester my subject is Syntax. I tried a few times to draw a tree using X-Bar theory and Dp's but I couldn't achieve. Can someone please draw a tree of the sentence down below for me ?

I am going mad while studying Syntax. I would be appreciate if you can do it for me. Thanks a lot.

"John says that Mary believes their daughter’s constant failing of her classes surprises her teachers very much."

Comment: Please show how far you got on your own. This will increase the chances of getting a useful answer.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about help with particular syntax trees.

Comment: Plz can anyone provide me with the rules of the movements used in the trees drawings (head movement , NP movement , WH movement)

Comment: why X-Bar theory is better than others?

Comment: X-bar theory isn't always better than others. The great thing about X-bar is that it captures similarities between different types of phrases (e.g. parallels between IP and DP). But it doesn't work for all languages - Australian languages, for example, have little to none configurationality, and the applicability of X-bar structures to such languages is often contested. Warlpiri likely has only an IP, for example, while Jiwarli has virtually none.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below you can see how I would do it. I didn't use triangles to be clearer.

I follow Carnie (2012), just instead of a TP, a tense phrase, I used an IP, an inflectional phrase (see Tallerman 2005). Supposedly the IP structure is the structure that all finite verbs have and all finite verbs have an inflection as far as European languages are concerned.

[image]

XX      To generate this tree:
[IP [NP [N' [N John]]] [I' [VP [V' [V says] [CP [C' [C that] [IP [NP [N' [N Mary]]] [I' [VP [V' [V believes] [CP [C' [C ∅] [IP
[DP [DP [D' [D their] [NP [N' [N daughter]]]]][D' [D ’s] [NP [N' [AdjP [Adj' [Adj constant]]] [N' [N failing]] [PP [P' [P of] [DP [D' [D her] [NP [N' [N classes]]]]]]]]]]] [I' [VP [V' [V' [V surprises]][DP [D' [D her] [NP [N' [N teachers]]]]]][AdvP [Adv' [Adv very much]]

Comment: There're a few small labelling errors here: the DP *her teachers* should be the sister of *V*, since its the complement of *V*, not a *V'*-level adjunct. The *AdvP* *very much* is an adjunct, not a specifier - it should be adjoined to *VP*. All of the *IP* projections are unheaded - all should have an *I* head which is missing. The bracketed version also doesn't match up with the tree: if i feed it into http://ironcreek.net/phpsyntaxtree/ it shows 62 open brackets and only 46 closed brackets. There should be 62 closed brackets.

Comment: Well, I did manage to generate the tree despite the lack of closed brackets. So, to generate the tree, you can actually use the code below.

Comment: You generated the tree using the bracketed representation? That shouldn't be possible. Even just visually inspecting the AdvP at the end, it's easy to see that it's missing a closed bracket. A bracketed representation just isn't well-formed unless all of the opened brackets are matched with a closed bracket.

Comment: The bracketed representation isn't wellformed, and it still draws the tree in the image: put it in here http://mshang.ca/syntree/.

Comment: The head of IPs in English is a modal verb or an auxiliary verb. Finite verbs that are neither an auxiliary nor a modal verb have a potential auxiliary or modal verb within them, because if you negate them, these verbs can specify the auxiliary needed. "Peter fell"> "Peter didn't fall".
This is short version of the explanation that was given to me by my Syntax professor at Oxford while she was drawing an unheaded IP. I have a slide from a lecture with an unheaded IP and relevant references if you'd like to see them.

Comment: In the help section of the syntax tree generator you link to, it says: "This app will build the tree as you type and will attempt to close any brackets that you may be missing.". I.e. it tries to repair any open brackets and draws a corresponding tree. phpSyntaxTree just fails to generate anything if the bracketed representation is ill-formed, which in this case it is. Your professor might have unheaded IPs, but in X'-theory, every XP simply *must* have a head X, so whatever your professor is doing it isn't X'-theory. In G&B theory, the affix originates in *I* and 'hops' onto the finite verb.

Comment: unheaded XPs are allowed at c-structure in LFG (Lexical Functional Grammar), and given that Oxford is well-known as a centre for LFG, i'm guessing that this is what your professor was doing.

Comment: It repairs the code, and generates the tree. If someone had commented they needed to generate the tree, I'd have provided them with the tree generator I used. I don't see the problem.
I don't get what you mean by 'hops'.
Her trees are those assumed in the theory of Lexical Functional Grammar (Bresnan 2001; Dalrymple 2001); they look similar but not identical to the trees usually assumed in Principles and Parameters/ Minimalist Theory (Carnie 2013; Adger 2003).

Comment: If she neglected the differences and used those trees to explain Principles and Parameters/Minimalist Theory, and x'-theory as well, I consider the differences can't be so huge I can't use their structure to answer a question about a x'-theory tree from someone who couldn't even start to draw it.

Comment: Bracketing is just a different way of representing constituency, and i thought you might be interested in knowing that the one you gave was ill-formed. It's not something that's up for extended discussion, just an observation. Affix-hopping is a morphological operation in generative syntax, it's covered in Carnie's textbook, which you give as a reference. The errors i pointed out were all relative to the framework presented in Carnie (2012), which i'm reasonably familiar with. This will be my final response, as i think this is becoming unproductive.

Comment: Yes, this is becoming unproductive, I don't like pedantic observations and yours were beyond the scope of what the questioner needs.
I don't think the questioner would be able to notice the differences between tree from different theories, since he couldn't even start drawing his own trees. I assume he'll be more interested in the general image rather than in its details.
I follow Carnie (see how I analysed the Saxon genitive?), and still as far as IPs are concerned I still find LFG to be more convincing.
I couldn't remember about 'hopping'; I'm kind of new to syntax.

Comment: I doubt you thought I might be interested in knowing that the bracketing I gave is ill-formed, unless you think I skipped 16 brackets without noticing.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the further information :) I was really confused about the tree of this sentence. It is quite complex but now I can understand clearly :) Please if you have questions, feel free to ask if I can help :)

Comment: No worries, it's a good exercise for me, I need to draw more trees.
I think you should accept one of the two answers as correct at this point. Near each answer, there's a tick sign to flag it as the one you regard as correct.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the basic X'-theoretic tree structure. The usual provisos apply - you'll get different answers depending on who you ask, but i think most would agree with the basic constituent structure i give here. Note that the inflection on the lexical verb is meant to originate on the *I* head, but i'm agnostic about the operation by which it ends up being spelled out as an affix on the verb. I'm also glossing over the fine structure of the DPs, because getting into that would raise some pretty complex issues.

[image]

Note that the sentence is ambiguous - the most salient reading is the one where the adverbial *very much* scopes over the most deeply embedded VP *surprised her teachers*. This is the reading i've represented above by adjoining the adverbial to the most deeply embedded VP. Other readings could be captured by adjoining *very much* to higher level VPs.

Note: The tree diagram was built using [phpSyntaxTree](http://ironcreek.net/phpsyntaxtree/).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the further information :) I was really confused about the tree of this sentence. It is quite complex but now I can understand clearly :) Please if you have questions, feel free to ask if I can help :)